# Magento 2.0.17 Category page Error - Uncaught ReferenceError: updateContent is not defined

Tags: magento2, category-tree

I am creating a `Root/Sub Category` from Category page. But in console, showing following error:

[image]

I am using `magento v2.0.7`.

Browser: Chrome latest version